# How to sort a column by date after Query combined multiple sheets

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets

I've created a query of multiple sheets in google combining marketing email streams.  How do I make the 1st column sort by date?  Here is the query I am currently using.

```
=query({'Warm Up and One Big Thing'!A3:K;'ETO Marketing'!A3:K;'ETO Fulfillment'!A3:K},"select * where Col1 is not Null")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({'Warm Up and One Big Thing'!A3:K;'ETO Marketing'!A3:K;'ETO Fulfillment'!A3:K},
 "where Col1 is not null
  order by Col1 asc")
```